Why am I being told "Failed init device" when I try to upload a file to my stm32 device?
I am trying to use platformio to program an stm32 device with libopencm3 on a laptop running ubuntu. The code compiles but when I try to run it it doesn't work an instead says it "Failed to init device" and "*** [upload] Error 1".
It isn't that it can't see the device because if I try to upload it without anything plugged in it gives a different error. I suspect it might be because my 99-platformio-udev.rules. I tried to follow the instructions on the platformio site. To that end I do have a file named 99-platformio-udev.rules at /etc/udev/rules.d/99-platformio-udev.rules that does match the most updated one on the website and did do sudo service udev restart, however I think I might be doing the next step wrong. It says

Ubuntu/Debian users may need to add own “username” to the “dialout” group if they are not “root”, doing this issuing
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
sudo usermod -a -G plugdev $USER


but I'm not sure what it means by that, so I tried to run the commands as is but I'm assuming that is wrong. What should I do? Below I will put the devices connection to the laptop, how I input the command, and the full output/error. If there is any other information needed please ask
the connection
my usermod command
Here is platformio.ini
platformio.ini
Processing genericSTM32F446RE (platform: ststm32; board: genericSTM32F446RE; framework: libopencm3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/ststm32/genericSTM32F446RE.html
PLATFORM: ST STM32 (17.3.0) > STM32F446RE (128k RAM. 512k Flash)
HARDWARE: STM32F446RET6 180MHz, 128KB RAM, 512KB Flash
DEBUG: Current (blackmagic) External (blackmagic, jlink, stlink)
PACKAGES: 
 - framework-libopencm3 @ 1.10000.200730 (1.0.0) 
 - tool-dfuutil @ 1.11.0 
 - tool-dfuutil-arduino @ 1.11.0 
 - tool-openocd @ 3.1200.0 (12.0) 
 - tool-stm32duino @ 1.0.1 
 - toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi @ 1.70201.0 (7.2.1)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> https://bi
{need to seperate the next part to post because its a shortened url but its one line}
t.ly/configure-pio-ldf
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Checking size .pio/build/genericSTM32F446RE/firmware.elf
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
RAM:   [          ]   0.0% (used 12 bytes from 131072 bytes)
Flash: [          ]   0.3% (used 1692 bytes from 524288 bytes)
Configuring upload protocol...
AVAILABLE: blackmagic, dfu, jlink, serial, stlink
CURRENT: upload_protocol = serial
Looking for upload port...
Auto-detected: /dev/ttyACM0
Uploading .pio/build/genericSTM32F446RE/firmware.bin
Failed to init device.
stm32flash Arduino_STM32_0.9

http://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/arduino_stm32

Using Parser : Raw BINARY
Interface serial_posix: 115200 8E1

*** [upload] Error 1
================================================================ [FAILED] Took 1.86 seconds ================================================================

 *  The terminal process "platformio 'run', '--target', 'upload'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 


You seem to be using the rogerclarkmelbourne's Arduino implementation for STM32 instead of the more common stm32duino implementation. And instead of stlink, which is probably best suited for Nucleo boards, you seem to be using another upload tool. Do you have a special reason for it? Can you show your platformio.ini file?


You are better to use board = nucleo_f446re in your platformio.ini than genericSTM32F446RE. 2) If you have the line board_build.core = maple, delete it. 3) Change upload_protocol = serial to upload_protocol = stlink. If all those changes still doesn't work, consult ST STM32 on platformio website or provide your platformio.ini

